# Lighten background of tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, tikz-fadings

In a TikZ picture, I am placing text nodes on a dark background.
To enhance visibility, I want to lighten the background behind the node, irrespective of what it is.
Thereby it would be nice if the area that is lightened didn't have a sharp boundary, but faded out instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% dark background:
\fill[black!0.8] (0,0) circle (1);
% this would also put light gray behind the node if the background is white:
\node[fill=light gray] at (0,0) {x};
% this kind of does what I want, but it would be nice if the lightening faded out:
\node[preaction={fill=white,opacity=0.5,blend mode=screen}] at (0,0) {x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post `MWE` always as in executable format

Comment: As requested, please post a complete minimal working example, starting by `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Feel free to add also a graphic description of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 5):

When trying to create a MWE, I accidentally found a solution (hadn't been aware of how the fading library works):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\tikzfading[name=fade out, inner color=black!40, outer color=black]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% dark background:
\fill[black!80] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
% nodes with lightened background
\node[circle, fill=white, inner sep=0.5,path fading=fade out] at (0.5,0.5) {x};
\node[circle, fill=white, inner sep=0.5,path fading=fade out] at (0.5,1) {x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Please let me know if you know a better way of doing this, or if there could be any problem with this. Also, is it possible to do this without defining a `\tikzfading` somewhere else in the document?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Like this (follows Andi Bauer's solution):

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\tikzfading[name=fade out, inner color=black!40, outer color=black]
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % dark background
        \fill[black!80] (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
        % nodes with lightened background
        \draw[fill=white, path fading=fade out] (1.5,2) circle(.5) node () {x};
        \draw[fill=white, path fading=fade out] (1.5,1) circle(.5) node () {x};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```